# Handle multiple uploaded files

Tags: php, file-upload

I am new to figuring out PHP. I have a lamp stack running and I am trying to insert and array of images into a table. In this table, there will be a ticketID that is retrieved from a newly created tuple and used to attach all images uploaded. So if there are three images uploaded they will all be inserted with ticket id 3 and the next column contains the actual image.

I tried to use  foreach loop that loops through each image file retrieved from the form and inserts them into the database one by one

```
$images = $_FILES['imageUpload'];

foreach($images as $img){
    // Here I am tryint to use $img in the SQL query
}
```

this keeps giving me a cannot convert array into string message on the line with $sql. i originally had the foreach loop inside after the $sql variable and concatenated it as it looped.
I read around and i saw that maybe i need to put the files in the /uploads directory of my database? but i wanted it in a table for easy sorting. I am under the impression that my syntax is correct as $images is the array and $img should be the individual objects inside, similar to a for .. of loop.

Please give any advice! Let me know if i need to upload any other parts of my code.

Comment: `$_FILES['imageUpload']` does not hold the actual image data but an array (for each image) with a file pointer to the temporary file among other values. See here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php You need to use `move_uploaded_file` to store the image somewhere (e.g. an `uploads` folder). And it's generally not the best idea to store the file's data inside your database, but a path to the file.

Comment: Topical, but not secure/stable: [how to insert file name into mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47669033/2943403) and [How to store file name in database, with other info while uploading image to server using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/450876/2943403) and [Using PHP to upload file and add the path to MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17153624/2943403) At least this one uses prepared statements: [Upload file name to SQL via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44062933/2943403)

Comment: There seems to be a plethora of pages NOT implementing prepared statements (ugh). [Write each uploaded file name to SQL database (PHP, MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62531715/2943403).  This page uses prepared statements but isn't terribly helpful: [How to insert file name, title in table and upload file on server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42969136/2943403)

Comment: *Before* even starting to meddle with SQL, you have to get the actual filenames. This is simply a logic. I mean, you are trying to use $img in the sql query without even checking what you actually have. Not to mention that indeed you have to store files on your serer first. Please learn to do **one thing at a time**. Upload files first. Collect filenames. Make sure it's indeed filenames and not anything else. Make sure it's correct filenames. **Only then** start with SQL, using prepared statements.